# Как безопасно перезаписать файл php

Tags: php

Пытаюсь перезаписать файл кодом:

```
    $filename = "file.txt";
    $file_handle = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($file_handle, $text); 
    fclose($file_handle);
```

Но перезаписывает только если на нем стоят права 777, насколько понимаю после таких прав его сможет поменять любой желающий, ставлю 755 или 775 уже не перезаписывает, как сделать это безопаснее?

Comment: ставите 755 чем, тем же скриптом или руками. что бы 777 не требовалось php должно выполняться под пользователем - владельцем файла

Comment: под каким пользователем и группой у вас работает php, и под какими реквизитами заходят «любые желающие»?

Comment: `chown www-data:www-data` для файла сделайте, тогда php скрипты смогут его перезаписать

Comment: некоторые редакторы позволяют "изменить" файл, даже не созданный вами, какие бы права на файле не стояли. Делается это простым удалением файла и созданием нового с тем же содержимым. Чтобы такого не было, надо поставить на папочку с файлом `sticky bit`, тогда удалять файл смогут только его создатели. В частности, таким образом защищены файлы в папке `/tmp`. Сделать это можно, например, так: `chmod +t /your/folder`